# Python void return type annotation

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing, nonetype

In python 3.x, it is common to use return type annotation of a function, such as:

```
def foo() -> str:
    return "bar"
```

What is the correct annotation for the "void" type?

I'm considering 3 options:

1. `def foo() -> None:`

   - not logical IMO, because `None` is not a type,
2. `def foo() -> type(None):`

   - using the best syntax I know for obtaining `NoneType`,
3. `def foo():`

   - omit explicit return type information.

Option 2. seems the most logical to me, but I've already seen some instances of 1.

Comment: FWIW, Python doesn't have functions with `void` return type. Any function (or branch in a function) without an explicit `return` will return `None`. I assume the OP understands that, this comment is mostly for the benefit of future readers...

Comment: Well, this question is not as popular as "why does my function return None in Python?" (I made this question up), so probably most readers already know the default behavior. The dilemma 1 vs 2 is solved in the answer. But what about 3? For "procedures" I actually would prefer option 3, without useless clutter (after all, this function doesn't return anything).

Comment: @TomaszGandor Agree. When a function or a method contains no return statement it is needless to specify its return type.

Comment: It is true that just using `None` for type hinting seems not logical because it is not a type, unless one knows that internally `None` is interpreted as `type(None)`, which is `NoneType`.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

This is straight from [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#using-none) documentation:

> When used in a type hint, the expression `None` is considered equivalent to `type(None)`.

And, as you can see most of the examples use `None` as return type.

Comment: To clarify, choose option 1 above.

Comment: What about the NoReturn type https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-noreturn-type ?

Comment: @asmaier according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570144/type-hint-that-a-function-never-returns) which cites [PEP 484 — Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)
 `NoReturn` type is used "...to annotate functions that never return normally. For example, a function that unconditionally raises an exception..."

Comment: To add to this point -- there is a class NoneType which is NOT the same as None.  (None != type(None)). If you are inspecting the return type of say a function with -> None typing hint. You want to be checking if typing.get_type_hints(func)['return'] == type(None)

Comment: Also FWIW, VS Code likes 1, not 2.  I'm just getting comfy with VS Code, so don't confuse me with an expert.

Answer (score 141):

TLDR: The idiomatic equivalent of a `void` return type annotation is `-> None`.

```
def foo() -> None:
    ...
```

This matches that a function without `return` or just a bare `return` evaluates to `None`.

```
def void_func():  # unannotated void function
    pass

print(void_func())  # None
```

---

Omitting the return type does *not* mean that there is no return value. As per [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-meaning-of-annotations):

> For a checked function, the default annotation for arguments and for the return type is `Any`.

This means the value is considered dynamically typed and statically [supports any operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any). That is practically the opposite meaning of `void`.

---

Type-hinting in Python does not strictly require actual types. For example, annotations may use strings of type names: `Union[str, int]`, `Union[str, 'int']`, `'Union[str, int]'` and various variants are equivalent.

Similarly, the type annotation `None` is considered *to mean* "is of `NoneType`". This can be used in other situations as well as return types, though you will see it most often as a return-type annotation:

```
bar : None

def foo(baz: None) -> None:
    return None
```

This also applies to generic types. For example, you can use `None` in `Generator[int, None, None]` to indicate a generator does not take or return values.

---

Even though PEP 484 suggests that `None` means `type(None)`, you *should  not* use the latter form explicitly. The type-hinting specification does *not* include any form of `type(...)`. This is technically a runtime expression, and its support is entirely up to the type checker. The mypy project is [considering whether to remove support](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/640) for `type(None)` and remove it from 484 as well.

> Or maybe we should update PEP 484 to not suggest that `type(None)` is valid as a type, and `None` is the only correct spelling? There should one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it etc.
>
> --- [JukkaL, 18 May 2018](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/640#issuecomment-390030201)