# Type hint that a function never returns

Tags: python, type-hinting

Python's new [type hinting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) feature allows us to type hint that a function returns `None`...

```
def some_func() -> None:
    pass
```

... or to leave the return type unspecified, which the PEP dictates should cause static analysers to assume that any return type is possible:

> Any function without annotations should be treated as having the most general type possible

However, how should I type hint that a function will never return? For instance, what is the correct way to type hint the return value of these two functions?

```
def loop_forever():
    while True:
        print('This function never returns because it loops forever')

def always_explode():
    raise Exception('This function never returns because it always raises')
```

Neither specifying `-> None` nor leaving the return type unspecified seems correct in these cases.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Even though “[PEP 484 — Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)” standard mentioned both in question and in the answer yet nobody quotes its section: [The `NoReturn` type](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-noreturn-type) that covers your question.

Quote:

> The `typing` module provides a special type `NoReturn` to annotate functions that never return normally. For example, a function that unconditionally raises an exception:

```
from typing import NoReturn

def stop() -> NoReturn:
    raise RuntimeError('no way')
```

The section also provides examples of the wrong usages. Though it doesn’t cover functions with an endless loop, in type theory they both equally satisfy *never returns* meaning expressed by that special type.

Comment: Julian and I can probably be forgiven for not noticing the `NoReturn` type in PEP 484 when I asked this question in July 2016, given that it didn't exist yet and wouldn't be added to the PEP until [almost a year later](https://github.com/python/peps/commit/881c6bebdb79d3a51dea0a467e81abed410e5570). Nonetheless, yep, this looks like it's now the correct answer.

Comment: Wow! So that update is considerably fresh for today for a three-year-old document but it lacks header like “Last Modified” as in [PEP 0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/). Also, now it gives me a hint of why my IDE does not recognize `NoReturn` type from `typing` yet no real problems during runtime.

Answer (score 7):

From Python 3.11, the new *bottom type* [`typing.Never`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Never) should be used to type functions that don't return, as

```
from typing import Never

def always_explode() -> Never:
    raise
```

This replaces `typing.NoReturn`

> ... to make the intended meaning more explicit.

I'm guessing at some point they'll deprecate `NoReturn` in that context, since both are valid in 3.11.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the docs. Note the `NoReturn` docs say: *"Special type indicating that a function never returns. ... `NoReturn` can **also be used as a bottom type**, a type that has no values. Starting in Python 3.11, the Never type should be used **for this concept** instead."* - emphasis mine. The docs are treating a function not returning and a "bottom type" as distinct "concepts", and saying you should use `Never` to express the concept of a bottom type but `NoReturn` to express the concept of a function never returning. I don't think a deprecation is on the cards!

Comment: @MarkAmery the docs are pretty unclear as a whole, but for `Never` it explicitly says _This can be used to define a function that should never be called, or a function that never returns:_

Comment: @MarkAmery which is odd, because the [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/30842) and [feature request](https://bugs.python.org/issue46475) both only talk about it as a bottom type. Clarification is needed

Comment: fwiw I think having two distinct things with one meaning is just moving the confusion. At least, I'm now confused but wasn't before

Comment: Funnily enough, the name `Never` also (as I understand) refers to functions not returning, relying on an awkward zeugma to be explained (“this function returns `int`” vs “this function returns `Never`” = “never returns”). So it’s not like the new name is any clearer or less tied to return values.

Answer (score 2):

In july 2016, there was no answer to this question yet (now there is `NoReturn`; see [the new accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47395859/1166087)). These were some of the reasons:

- When a function doesn't return, there is no return value (not even `None`) that a type could be assigned to. So you are not actually trying to annotate a type; you are trying to annotate *the absence of a type*.
- The type hinting PEP has only just been adopted in the standard, as of Python version 3.5. In addition, the PEP only advises on what type annotations should *look like*, while being intentionally vague on *how to use them*. So there is no standard telling us how to do anything in particular, beyond the examples.
- The PEP has a section [Acceptable type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id14) stating the following:

  > Annotations must be valid expressions that evaluate without raising exceptions at the time the function is defined (but see below for forward references).
  >
  > Annotations should be kept simple or static analysis tools may not be able to interpret the values. For example, dynamically computed types are unlikely to be understood. (This is an intentionally somewhat vague requirement, specific inclusions and exclusions may be added to future versions of this PEP as warranted by the discussion.)

  So it tries to discourage you from doing overly creative things, like throwing an exception inside a return type hint in order to signal that a function never returns.
- Regarding exceptions, [the PEP states the following](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id44):

  > No syntax for listing explicitly raised exceptions is proposed. Currently the only known use case for this feature is documentational, in which case the recommendation is to put this information in a docstring.
- There is a recommendation on [type comments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id37), in which you have more freedom, but even that section doesn't discuss how to document the absence of a type.

There is one thing you could try in a slightly different situation, when you want to hint that a parameter or a return value of some "normal" function should be a callable that never returns. The [syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id17) is `Callable[[ArgTypes...] ReturnType]`, so you could just omit the return type, as in `Callable[[ArgTypes...]]`. However, this doesn't conform to the recommended syntax, so strictly speaking it isn't an acceptable type hint. Type checkers will likely choke on it.

Conclusion: you are ahead of your time. This may be disappointing, but there is an advantage for you, too: you can still influence how non-returning functions should be annotated. Maybe this will be an excuse for you to get involved in the standardisation process. :-)

I have two suggestions.

1. Allow omitting the return type in a `Callable` hint *and* allow the type of anything to be forward hinted. This would result in the following syntax:

   ```
   always_explode: Callable[[]]
   def always_explode():
       raise Exception('This function never returns because it always raises')
   ```
2. Introduce a [bottom type like in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bottom):

   ```
   def always_explode() -> ⊥:
       raise Exception('This function never returns because it always raises')
   ```

These two suggestions could be combined.