# Type hint for return, return None, and no return at all?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Is there any difference in the return type hint amongst these three functions?

```
def my_func1():
    print("Hello World")
    return None

def my_func2():
    print("Hello World")
    return

def my_func3():
    print("Hello World")
```

Should they all have `-> None` return type hint, since that's what they in fact return, explicitly or implicitly? Or should `my_func2` or `my_func3` have literally no return type hint?

Motivations for asking are [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15300550/5069105), and [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15300671/5069105), and the fact that I'm learning [Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python void return type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797282/python-void-return-type-annotation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hint that a function never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570144/type-hint-that-a-function-never-returns)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

They all should have the `-> None` return type, since they all clearly return `None`.

Note that there also exists the [**`typing.NoReturn`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NoReturn) type for functions that actually never return anything, e.g.

```
from typing import NoReturn

def raise_err() -> NoReturn:
    raise AssertionError("oops an error")
```

Other types of functions  (pointed out by [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)) that actually never return and thus should be type hinted with `-> NoReturn` would be for example an event loop that only ends using `sys.exit` or any of the [**`os.exec*`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl) functions

> Or should `my_func2` or `my_func3` have literally no return type hint?

In my opinion, they *should* always have a type hint, since as [@yedpodtrzitko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217723/yedpodtrzitko) said in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64063840/9835872), functions with no type hints are by default not type checked by Mypy at all, and their return values are basically treated as if they would've been typed to be `Any`. This greatly reduces the benefits of type checking, and that's one of the reasons I always use the Mypy setting `disallow_untyped_defs = True` for new projects.

Answer (score 9):

if your function don't have any type hint in its signature, mypy won't check them at all by default. Consider following:

`$ cat foo.py`

```
def foo():
    """this function has no type hint in its signature 
    it won't be checked and the error will be ignored."""
    "foo" + 1
    return None

def bar() -> None:
    """this has type hint in the signature
    it will be checked and error will be reported"""
    "bar" + 1
    return None
```

```
$ mypy ./foo.py
foo.py:6: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```