# typehints -> None or leave blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

Using python 3, one has the option to use typehints.

If a function returns None, should one add this, or leave it blank?

i.e.

```
def hint(p: str) -> None:
    ...

def no_hint(p: str):
    ...
```

And which PEP addresses this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python void return type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797282/python-void-return-type-annotation)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Be explicit* and always include `-> None` for functions that return `None`

That's because otherwise, for functions *that don't take arguments*, the type checker will assume that you did not use type hints at all. For example, is `def foo():` going to return `None`, or was it simply not type hinted?

[PEP 484 - *Type Hints*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484) indirectly addresses this:

> Note that the return type of `__init__` ought to be annotated with `-> None`. The reason for this is subtle. If `__init__` assumed a return annotation of `-> None`, would that mean that an argument-less, un-annotated `__init__` method should still be type-checked? Rather than leaving this ambiguous or introducing an exception to the exception, we simply say that `__init__` ought to have a return annotation; the default behavior is thus the same as for other methods.

Comment: But in the OP's example, the function does take an argument, so the ambiguity is removed no?

Comment: @Chris You mean to say that since the argument is type hinted, it should be assumed that the return type is too == no return type hint == no return value? I think that's covered by *"Rather than leaving this ambiguous or introducing an exception to the exception…"*.

Comment: @deceze That's exactly what I meant, but on reflection, I agree, it's still ambiguous and could lead to confusion, thanks

Comment: @Chris_Rands: what deceze said; if you only annotated functions without arguments with `-> None`, and didn't bother with functions that do have arguments, you are only setting yourself up for failure as you *will* forget to apply the annotations.

Comment: Why use `None` as the annotation type opposed to `NoneType`? For example: `type(3): <class 'int'>` vs `type(None): <class 'NoneType'>`.

Comment: @303 because `NoneType` needs an extra import. Since `None` is a singleton it was made an exception, see [PEP 484 Type Hints](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#using-none)