# Return None from python function annotated with mypy, multiple return types

Tags: python, function, return-type, static-typing, mypy

I come from a Typescript background. I'm bringing static type checking into a python project I'm working on (using mypy).

In Typescript, it is valid to return null from a function that is annotated to return something else, i.e. a string:

```typescript
function test(flag: boolean): string {
    if(flag) {
        return 'success';
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is also valid to annotate your function to have multiple potential return types, i.e. string or boolean:

```typescript
function test(flag: boolean): string | boolean {
    if(flag) {
        return 'success';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But, in python using mypy, I'm disallowed from returning None from a function that is annotated to return `str`.

```python
def test(flag: bool) -> str:
    if flag:
        return 'success'
    else:
        return None
        # [mypy] error:Incompatible return value type (got "None", expected "str")
```

Furthermore, I don't see a way to annotate multiple return types, i.e. `str | None`.

How should I approach something like this using mypy? Functions that return None from the error state are all over my codebase.

Comment: Could you just return an empty string instead?

Comment: That is logical: In Python, `None` is not rally a "null reference", it is an object (just like any other object), and its type is `NoneType`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah, it makes sense the None type in python is different than a null reference in javascript.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Okay, I found what I was missing in the documentation thanks to @zsol on the mypy gitter!

Two helpful mypy features are the Optional and Union types that can be imported from python's typing module. [Documentation here.](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html?highlight=Union#union-types)

If you want to annotate that the function can potentially return None in addition to the primary type, e.g. `str`, use `Optional`:

```python
from typing import Optional

def test(flag: bool) -> Optional[str]:
    if flag:
        return 'success'
    else:
        return None
```

If you want to annotate that the function can potentially return multiple types, e.g. `str | bool`, use `Union`:

```python
from typing import Union

def test(flag: bool) -> Union[str, bool]:
    if flag:
        return 'success'
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: You can also use `no_strict_optional = True` (or `--no-strict-optional` in cmd line) to allows accept `None` for any expected type.

Comment: what about functions that don't have a return statement? i read you would use `def func() -> None` but `None` is not a type. It is an object and its type is `NoneType` so how come we don't do `def func() -> NoneType` ? EDIT: oh I found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797282/python-void-return-type-annotation

Comment: Python doesn't have functions with void return type. Any function (or branch in a function) without an explicit return will return None. The default for a missing annotation is Any, not None. If you leave out the return annotation, type checkers will treat your function as returning Any. https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-meaning-of-annotations