# TypeChecking for a function that returns None

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, typechecking, static-typing, python-typing

Consider the recursive implementation of factorial function -

```py
from typing import Optional

def factorial(val: int) -> Optional[int]:
    if val<0:
        return None
    if val==0:
        return 1
    return val*factorial(val-1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(square_root(3))
```

I am using `mypy` for static type checking. It throws me the following error -

```sh
type-hints.py:8: error: Unsupported operand types for * ("int" and "None")
type-hints.py:8: note: Right operand is of type "Optional[int]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I tried using `Optional` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264233/return-none-from-python-function-annotated-with-mypy-multiple-return-types) stackoverflow question. But it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

**Questions** -

1. How to specify return type when the function returns `None`?
2. Seems a bit surprising to me that *mypy* was able to envision a situation where multiplication between `int` and `None` might occur. For example - If I remove `int` for *val* argument and call the factorial function with a float, it might throw such error.

Comment: Can you clarify what behaviour you expect? ``factorial`` *is* of type (int) -> Optional[int], so ``val*factorial(val-1)`` is of type ``:int * :Optional[int]``. MyPy has no way of knowing that ``None`` only occurs for ``val < 0``.

Comment: Can you answer my first question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyPy is correct that the function is not well-typed. The signature of the function is `(int) -> Optional[int]`, making `val*factorial(val-1)` *possibly* erroneous. That `None` only occurs for `val < 0` is *not* static type information.

Instead of returning `None` for invalid input, raise an exception. This makes the function statically well-typed, without removing the error handling.

```py
def factorial(val: int) -> int:
    if val<0:
        raise ValueError("factorial() not defined for negative values")
    if val==0:
        return 1
    return val*factorial(val-1)
```

---

If returning `None` is required for some reason, explicitly annotate that the expression is sound and does not need checking.

```py
def factorial(val: int) -> int:
    if val<0:
        return None
    if val==0:
        return 1
    return val*factorial(val-1)  # type: ignore
```

Comment: Cool, that could be one way of doing it. But does it have anything to do with `mypy` or `python` version. For example - I was looking at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rytP_vIjzeE) and if you check at about 5:00-5:30, the guy doesn't run into any error & he seems to be using 3.6

Comment: The treatment of Optional was much more lax in the past, and is slowly being changed for consistent static typing. For example, see [Can I omit Optional if I set default to None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732402/can-i-omit-optional-if-i-set-default-to-none). In specific, earlier versions of MyPy allowed implicit None and would silently ignore invalid operations on None.