# Typing unused arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

I have a function that **has** to take two arguments, like:

```
def f(first_arg: int, unused_arg) -> int:
    first_arg += 1
    return first_arg
```

I want to type my function, what should be the type of unused_arg ? From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797282/python-void-return-type-annotation) I guess `None` could be used.

For context, I'm using `lax.scan` from `jax` which needs a function with two arguments even when the second one is unused.

Comment: If it's unused, does it even matter? `Any` makes the most sense IMO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any`?

```
from typing import Any

def f(first_arg: int, unused_arg: Any) -> int:
    ...
```

Comment: I guess I can use Any. It is more of a semantic question anyway

Answer (score 1):

The doc (https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.scan.html) gives the type of `f` as:

```
Callable[[~Carry, ~X], Tuple[~Carry, ~Y]]
```

so I'd maybe do it with a `TypeVar` named `X` if I didn't have a more specific type:

```
from typing import TypeVar

X = TypeVar("X")

def f(first_arg: int, _second_arg: X) -> int:
    ...
```

Using `Any` can be problematic since it masks typechecking -- it doesn't matter for a variable you aren't ever using, but if your function implementation ever changes you might not realize that the formerly-unused arg isn't being typechecked, whereas if you use a `TypeVar` you'll get errors if you make any assumptions that aren't backed up by a `bound` on that variable.  I try to avoid even importing `Any` just to make sure it's not creeping in anyplace without me noticing.

Note that per the doc it seems like your `f` is expected to return a tuple of two items; I'm not sure if that matters for your use case.

The standard way (at least as enforced by linters I've used) of indicating an unused parameter is to prefix it with an underscore, so I'd do that instead of naming it `unused_arg`).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Never, from docs "This can be used to define a function that should never be called, or a function that never returns:".

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Never

```
from typing import Never

def never_call_me(arg: Never) -> None:
    pass
```